# WPF, C#. Есть ли какие то реализованные методы для получения playlistID from URL?

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube-api

Есть ссылки формата:
`https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_m_hUz1QLpP4-Qwz9zEgNisP68W01aCyTI`

И: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVi1iInu1eM&list=OLAK5uy_m_hUz1QLpP4-Qwz9zEgNisP68W01aCyTI&index=4&t=0s`

Нужно пропарсить их так что бы получить:
`OLAK5uy_m_hUz1QLpP4-Qwz9zEgNisP68W01aCyTI`

Есть ли уже какое то готовое решение?

Comment: да, регулярные выражения или IndexOf() + Substring()

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что возможно в библиотеки YouTubeApi, есть именно метод вроде: GetPlaylistId(string link);
Спрашиваю, чтобы самому не придумывать велосипед если он уже есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть готовое решение (найдено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/659929/12888024))

```cs
using System.Web;
```

```cs
Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_m_hUz1QLpP4-Qwz9zEgNisP68W01aCyTI");
string playlistCode = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("list");
```

Comment: Какой смысл дублировать ответ?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ наверное чтобы модератор смог связать этот ответ с английским SO, чтобы там появилось "на этот вопрос есть ответ на StackOverflow на русском". Здесь я этого примера не нашел.

Comment: Уже голос за закрытие висит от меня на русский аналог, не уж то так надо кинуть ответ было?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ упс, я не посмотрел, что внутри, думал там регулярки. Окей, ваша взяла. Но ответ оставлю, SO его почистит, если никто не плюсанет.

Comment: Привет еще один дубликат...